How can I accurately calculate the height of a firework from a video with some known parameters?
I have a video of some fireworks from my iPhone 13 pro ultra wide angle camera. I want to overlay an accurate grid of heights in the video. Something like a line every 10 meters. Here are the known parameters:

Video resolution is 3840 by 2160 pixels
Aspect ratio is 16:9
Lens focal length is 13mm equivalent
Lens horizontal field of view is 120 degrees
Firework point of launch plane, which is equal to zero meters, is 80 pixels from the bottom of the video frame
Horizontal distance from camera to launch point is 224 feet
Camera is angled 30 degrees
The camera lens is 6 feet above the horizontal launch point
The firework peaks at 1080 pixels from the bottom of the frame
When calibrating the camera manually using some basic trigonometry, it appears that the center of the frame at 1080 pixels is equal to 129 feet but I'm not sure I did it correctly nor how to translate that into a grid.

I'm nowhere near smart enough to code this by hand. I tried using ChatGPT to assist and it came up with some pretty cool looking Python scripts that felt promising, but none of them resulted in anything remotely accurate. I've tried downloading some photogrammetry software tools but they are all far out of my comfort zone.

I closed this question because there could be hundreds of ways to implement this; too many to enumerate here. Furthermore, a full answer to any one of them could require many pages or even a full book. Rather than asking for an approach, [edit] your question to focus on a more specific problem you encounter after you have chosen a method and attempted to implement it.

This feels more like a math question than a programming one, actually! Not a photographer, but I'll try the best I can. Also, JLarikka is right about the trajectory thing, but we can at least try to make some approximations. In particular, this gets much easier if we assume that all fireworks go roughly upwards from roughly the same launch site, which I think is pretty fair.
This will take a few steps.
1: Finding the angle between a given firework and the camera.
We need to find the angle between the camera-firework line and the direction the camera is looking in based on a given firework's height. To do this, let's construct a triangle between the (F)irework, (L)aunch site, and (C)amera.
  F
  |\
  | \
  |  \
  |   \
L ----- C

We know FL because that's the height of the firework, and CL is 224ft since it's the distance from the camera to the launch site. That makes mLCF=tan⁻¹(FL/224ft). But that's the angle between the camera-firework line and the ground; we want the angle between the camera-firework line and the camera's direction. Since we know both of them (the camera direction is still π/6), we can just subtract the two angles to get tan⁻¹(FL/224ft)-π/6. Note that this will sometimes give negative angles - that means the firework will show up below the center of the camera.
Takeaway: The angle between the camera direction and the camera-firework line is tan⁻¹(firework height/224)-π/6.
2: Converting the angle to a pixel measure.
Now that we have the angle, we need to figure out where it maps to on the screen. We don't need to consider the horizontal axis, so let's just take a look at a vertical slice containing the (T)op of the screen, (B)ottom of the screen, and (C)amera:
T
|\
| \
|  \ C
|  /
| /
|/
B

The first thing we need to do is find the distance from C to TB so we can use it for trig. You said TB was 2160px, and using the aspect ratio, the horizontal FOV, and this calculator, we can find that mBCT ≈ 90 degrees = π/2. Those measurements will let us find the distance.
To find the distance from C to TB, we only want to consider half of the triangle: T, C, and the (M)idpoint of TB.
  T
  |\
  | \
  |  \
M ---- C

TM=1080px and mMCT=π/4, so 1080px/CM=tan(π/4) and CM=1080px. This measurement doesn't mean anything on its own, but we need it for other trig stuff.
Now that we know CM, consider another triangle: this time, between the midpoint, the camera, and some random firework.
  F
  |\
  | \
  |  \
M ---- C

We calculated mMCF in part 1, but let's just call it θ for now. Since we know MC=1080px, we can say that FM/1080px=tan(θ) and FM=1080px * tan(θ). Based on how we built the triangle, FM shows how far the point should be above the middle of the screen. From there, the rest is easy: just add that number to 1080px (the middle of the screen) to get the height above the bottom of the screen. This will work even if the firework is below the screen. Since θ will be negative, our formula will give us a negative height, and adding that to 1080px will give us a point below the middle.
Takeaway: The screenwise height of a firework with an firework-camera angle of θ will be 1080tan(θ) + 1080.
3: Put it all together.
From part (1), we know that θ = tan⁻¹(firework height/224ft)-π/6. Plug that into our formula from part (2) to get:
y-coord = 1080px * tan(tan⁻¹(firework height/224ft)-π/6) + 1080px
Now we have to compensate for the camera height. Since the camera is 6 feet off the ground, the firework height we plug into the formula should be 6 less than its actual height - almost as if we dragged the camera and the firework down 6 feet each so the camera is on the ground.
y-coord = 1080 * tan(tan⁻¹((firework height-6)/224)-π/6) + 1080
Let's test out this formula with the firework you calculated. We want to get 1080 from plugging in 129 feet into this formula. It actually gives us 1059, which is not great, but it's also only about 2% off.
4: Pythonification
The last step is to make this a Python program. Ideally, we want a few things:

A function that outputs a camera y-coordinate for a given firework height.
A way to find every y-coordinate that will fit on screen.
A way to pretty-print all our data once we've calculated it.

1 and 3 are pretty easy. 2 is a little annoying since we have to set an upper bound, but a little trig gives that the highest firework that will fit on screen has a height of about 865 feet, so we can go with that. The complete program will be as follows:
import math

def y_coord(firework_height: int) -> int:
    angle: float = math.atan2(firework_height-6, 224) - math.pi/6
    return 1080 * math.tan(angle) + 1080

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Height\ty-coord")
    print("------\t-------")
    for height in range(0, 865, 10):
        print(f"{height}\t{int(round(y_coord(height)))}")


You can use the output from this to generate the positions of all the lines you're looking for and use whatever tool you need to actually draw them in.
Of course, you may need to do some customization (make the coords start from the top instead of the bottom, measure in feet instead of meters, change the step value, etc.), but this script should give you a framework to start from.
Fun problem, good luck, hope this solution wasn't completely wrong!
